# UIView reference returns NULL pointed ARC enabled

Tags: objective-c, uiview, null, automatic-ref-counting

I have ARC enabled so I am unsure as to why my reference is null.

My view controller instantiates a UIView ‘**theGrid**’ as soon as the view is loaded.

Later I have switch inside another class (MyOtherClass) that calls the UIViewContoller  `- (void) updateTheGrid:(id)sender` method, that method is called as per the NSLog, but when I output the UIView to see if it is there, its returns null.

What am I doing wrong? It was my impression that ARC keeps up with everything. I feel like my trouble is coming from mm "MyOtherClass" when I  `ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];` because I feel like that is just creating a new instance. But if that is the case, how am i suppose to reference the old instance and call the method?

**NSLOG OUTPUT**

```
[28853:c07] Intial Grid: <GridView: 0x8e423b0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <CALayer: 0x8e43780>>
[28853:c07] Update The Grid (null)
```

**GridView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GridView : UIView

- (void) gridUpdated;
@end
```

**GridView.m**

```
#import "GridView.h"
@implementation GridView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSLog(@"initWithFrame");

     }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
   NSLog(@"Grid Draw Rect");
}

- (void) gridUpdated {
    NSLog(@"GRID VIEW.m : Grid update called");
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GridView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
        GridView *theGrid;
}

@property (strong, retain) GridView * theGrid;
- (void) updateTheGrid : (id) sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GridView.h"

@interface ViewController () {}
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize theGrid;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //draw the grid
    theGrid = [[GridView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    NSLog(@"Intial Grid: %@", theGrid);
    [self.view addSubview:theGrid];
}

- (void) updateTheGrid : (id) sender{
    NSLog(@"Update The Grid %@", theGrid);
    [theGrid gridUpdated];
}

@end
```

**MyOtherClass.m**

```
- (void) mySwitch : (id) sender {
    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [vc updateTheGrid:sender];

}
```

Comment: where is ur updateThePaper method ? what is this means "@property (strong, retain) GridView * theGrid; "   ????

Comment: Sorry I updated the code to edit the typo. It should read updateTheGrid now. As for the '@property (strong, retain) GridView * theGrid;' I was trying different methods of maintain **theGrid** in memory or at least a way to reference it. Do I need that line? @Ramshad

Comment: the issue is not happening here.. if u don't mind,could u send the sample app to ramshadram90@gmail.com ? I can help u then..

Comment: Sent to your email address. It's in a zip file @Ramshad

Comment: I have posted the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not allocate `ViewController` object again in your `MyOtherClass.m` because it will create an new instance of `ViewController` and your previous objects which holds `ViewController` wil get disposed including theGrid.

So please declare a `weak` property of `ViewController` inside the `MyOtherClass.m` and assign  it while allocating  `MyOtherClass.m`

Example:

**ViewController class**

```
moc = [[MyOtherClass alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

 moc.vc = self;
```

**MyOtherClass.h**

```
@property(nonatomic,weak) ViewController *vc;
```

**MyOtherClass.m**

```
- (void) mySwitch : (id) sender {

   [self.vc updateTheGrid:sender];

}
```

Note:Take care about the forward declarations :)